# Listview no vb6?

Tags: sql-server, visual-basic-6

Iniciei programação com esta linguagem e gostaria de uma ajuda de como exibir dados que foram inseridos em textbox em um listview no vb6?

Comment: Como foi feito essa inserção?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na minha opinião esta linguagem é obsoleta, no entanto, é possível realizar a operação que deseja.

> "Como exibir dados que foram inseridos em **TextBox** em um **ListView** no VB6"

```
//Obter o texto do Textbox
Dim text As String = TextBox1.Text

//ColumnHeader associado ao texto
ListView1.ColumnsHeaders.Add("Coluna1")

//Adicionar texto ao ListView na Coluna1
ListView1.ListItems.Add(text)
```

Para esta pergunta esta é a resolução. Você também pode adicionar colunas ao controle por meio das propriedades do **IDE** que está a usar.

Answer (score 0):

Ok funcionou, grato pela ajuda.

Outro questionamento sobre listview com um exemplo bem genérico. Suponho que tenho uma tabela de "Alunos" em no banco de dados SQL server 2008 com os campos "matricula" e nome até aí consegui exibi-los na listview, to com dificuldade para 
fazer o crud de "pesquisar por nome do aluno" e exibir este resultado na listview. Como faço esse procedimento?
Obs.: O sistema ERP aqui da empresa onde trabalho foi desenvolvido nesta linguagem por tanto to correndo atrás de aprender o mais urgente possível, pois estou em treinamento. No aguardo

Comment: Seguem referências bons estudos,
http://www.macoratti.net/lstview2.htm
http://www.macoratti.net/vb_tdl1.htm
http://www.macoratti.net/listview.htm
http://www.macoratti.net/lstv_vb.htm
http://www.macoratti.net/lstview3.htm